# Sending additonal form data to controller in Rails `form_for` helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

If I have a User model and I use:

`form_for @user, url: {controller: :user, action: :create} do |f|`

I can add the fields I need by (for example) going:

`<%= f.text_field :name %>`

But on this particular admin page I am working on I want to send additional data back to my controller, data which is not part of the User model, i.e.

`<%= f.text_field :some_info %>`

This gives me a 'undefined method some_info` error.

Is there a way that I can get my form helper to allow me to set additional strings, to use as part of my controller logic?

Comment: I don't know if i understand, but i think you can use a [text_field_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag) to send data outside of model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@gFontaniva was correct, instead of

`<%= f.text_field :some_info %>`

You exclude it from the form variable, and use the tag method, as:

`<%= text_field :some_info, '' %>`

This then can be accessed from the controller, outside the scope of the form model, so the first example accessed:

`params[:user][:some_info]`

And the second version:

`params[:some_info]`

Exactly as I needed.

Answer (score 2):

We can have a method called `attr_accessor` in rails to define additional fields which are not in specified model.

Try like this:

Add below line in model.rb file

```
attr_accessor :some_info
```

and add this line to your form

```
<%= f.text_field :some_info %>
```